# background image disappears on hover on table row

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using `jQuery Datatables` to display my data. I can display my data alright but I need to add some image in front of some rows (which i'll be doing by adding a class to row I need to display an image against).

Now I can display image on some rows but as soon as I hover over row, Image disappears. I have tried adding z-index but nothing changed. Have anyone experienced this problem? I am using bootstrap CSS and js, can that be any issue?

I would also like to add, I also have `popover` effect on every row added as i also bring a popover on hovering over any row with some info.

Another issue I have is, as I am using `jQuery Datatable` to display data, datatable automatically adds `odd` and `even` class to table row and for some reason my image doesn't appear at all for any row which has class odd. I have tried deleting `odd` class from row but that doesn't make image appear which makes me believe that their may be something else going on.

If anyone has experienced this odd behaviour, can you please share your solution or any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any code, I'd hazard a guess that you are adding your image using `background: url(whatever.png)` and the `.odd` class and the `:hover` state are overriding this with `background:#ccc` or whatever colour it uses.

As I said this is just a guess some actual code and a fiddle would really help

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction Duncan, as i am using ````bootstrap.css```` and ````datatables.css```` files, both of these files were messing around with tr(2n+1) + tr(2n) child. Giving ````background-color: transparent !important;```` fixed both the problem for me.